# How to iterate through custom account object to get contacts from it

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list

I have created a page which displays records of account tab.the page that displays a list of record is pasted below.
what i want to implement is ..where i click a record,it should diplays the detail of record and this shold be done through apex.I have achieved this functionaloty but i am not sure how to fetch the related contatc from the SOQL ojct

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="recordPageCont">  
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!EditAccount}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!CancelButton}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Name}"/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.AccountNumber} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Type} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.industry} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Rating} "/>
     <b>Email</b> {!objAccount.Name}@salesforce.com
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Rating} "/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts Related With {!objaccount.name}"></apex:pageBlock>
<apex:form >

</apex:form>>
</apex:page>
```

below is my apex page.

what this pagedoes is fetch the details of the record which is clicked.

The id of the record is in variabla recId
What my question is how to display contact on the vf page.
some one told me that i have to iterate through the object "objAccount" to get the contact.

Please let me know how to do this

```
public class recordPageCont {
public Account objAccount{get;set;}
Public string recId{get;set;}

    public recordPageCont ()
    {
         recId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        objAccount =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating,(SELECT Name , MobilePhone,Title from Contacts) 
                     FROM account
                     WHERE ID = :recId ];
    }

    Public pagereference Editaccount()
    {
        Pagereference edtaccount = new Pagereference('/apex/editaccount?id='+recid);
        edtaccount.setredirect(true);
        return edtaccount;
    }

    public pagereference cancelButton()
    {
        Pagereference cnclbutton = new Pagereference('/apex/accountdisplay');
        cnclbutton.setredirect(true);
        return cnclbutton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the contact list from your subquery by treating it as the `List<Contact>` that it is. If the List has data, grab it and assign it to the contact display list.

```
Contact[] displayContacts {get;set;} //display in the vf page using a repeat

Account[] accts =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating,(SELECT Name , MobilePhone,Title from Contacts) 
                 FROM account
                 WHERE ID = :recId ];

Account acct = accts[0];
//acct.Contacts is a List<Contact>
if (!acct.Contacts.isEmpty()){
    displayContacts = acct.Contacts;
}
```

Comment: Expression must be a list type: Account at line 14 column 20 - this is the error i am getting for at line "accounts acct = accts[0]"

Comment: Looks like you have a typo - I'm assigning the result of the query to a list, and extracting the first element as the account eg `Account[] accts = [query];`  then `Account acct = accts[0];` - copy that exactly, don't forget the square brackets.

Comment: ur accts acount is equivalent to my objAccount account...right??
which i have declared like public Account objAccount{get;set;}

do i need to change to to somethig else???? @CaspNZ

Comment: objAccount is a single account, accts is an array - other than that, they are similar. So you could write `objAccount = accts[0];` to set your account

Comment: The code is not giving any error now...Thanks for ur help..But as i asked..how can i show the fields from display contact on VF page..
coz when i am writing below code..its giving me an error

<apex:outputField value="{!displayContacts.Rating} "/>

eror is "Error: Unknown property 'recordPageCont.displayContacts"

Comment: can i write something like :

 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!displayContacts}" var="a">
   
     
                        <apex:commandLink value="{!a.name}">
                        </apex:commandLink>